# Using psyco with py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe, psyco

In my main script, lets call this MyScript.py, I have it like this:

```
import psyco
psyco.full()
```

And then my setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os, glob

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

import psyco #speed up compilation
psyco.full()

def find_data_files(source,target,patterns):
    """Locates the specified data-files and returns the matches
    in a data_files compatible format.

    source is the root of the source data tree.
        Use '' or '.' for current directory.
    target is the root of the target data tree.
        Use '' or '.' for the distribution directory.
    patterns is a sequence of glob-patterns for the
        files you want to copy.
    """
    if glob.has_magic(source) or glob.has_magic(target):
        raise ValueError("Magic not allowed in src, target")
    ret = {}
    for pattern in patterns:
        pattern = os.path.join(source,pattern)
        for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                targetpath = os.path.join(target,os.path.relpath(filename,source))
                path = os.path.dirname(targetpath)
                ret.setdefault(path,[]).append(filename)
    return sorted(ret.items())
setup(
    name="MyScript",
    version="1.0",
    description="a script that does something",
    author="Keelx",
    data_files=find_data_files('.','',[
        'gfx/*',
        'data/*',
    ]),
    options={'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,'optimize': 2}},
    windows=[{'script': "MyScript.py"}],
    zipfile=None,
)
```

It creates a 'dist' folder, with the executable, a win9x executable, and the gfx and data folders next to the executable. However, when I run it it points me to a log which reads:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "MyScript.py", line 16, in 
>     File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
>     File "psyco__init__.pyo", line 64, in 
>   WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Documents and Settings\Keelx\Desktop\MyScriptFolder\dist\MyScript.exe\psyco\_psyco.pyd'

It would seem that the psyco module is not being put into the executable. I've been searching, and I haven't found a working solution to get py2exe to copy psyco over.

And please refrain from posting solutions along the lines of 'don't use py2exe'.

Thank you in advance whomever can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Hunting down py2exe errors appears to be an art to me. 
That said, I will at least offer something to try.
I py2exe'ed a psyco enabled python script and tossed it in the includes part of the setup. 
Thats the only part that looks different between your setup and my old one.

```
options = {'py2exe': {'packages': [ 'IPython'],
                      'includes': ["psyco"],
                     }
          }
```

Also I was never able to enable optimize. It always caused random errors. Best to leave that one off in my experience. I think it was matplotlib that caused those errors.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers,

Comment: Yeah I tried that at one point, had absolutely no effect. Would you care to explain the 'packages': ['IPython'] bit?

Comment: I was using IPython for a development console in my gtk application. It's in there just to have something in the packages field. Also another thing to try is to try having the psyco as a egg and not as a egg. I believe there were some issues with using easy_install for packages where I had to compile them or run the win32 .exe installers.